# When check is selected it has to display the form in div tag. div must be temporary disabled

Tags: javascript, html

This my code given below. I have to make form more attractive to the user. I have many forms, but i have listed below only one. when check box is checked. It has to display the div tag. which has to be temporary disable. It has to display below, the check box. I am new to html and javascript. But i have created something with help of w3.org. But now i am struck helpless. Experts please help me a way out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css"></style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2><u>Plans</u></h2>
    <div id="space"><br></div>
    <h3><u>1)Expenses</u></h3>
    <div id="space"><br></div>
    <div id="form">
    <form action="">
    <div id="Location"><input type="checkbox" name="placename" />Location
    <div id="editloc">
    <table>
    <tr><td>City:</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Please enter City name.." size="50"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>State:</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Please enter State name.." size="50" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Country:</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Please enter Country name.." size="50" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" value="save" /></td><td><input type="button" value="reset" /></td></tr>
    </table></div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pure javascript method. doesn't require any javascript library try this out

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowEditLoc(obj)
{
    document.getElementById("editloc").style.display = obj.checked ? "block" : "none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2><u>Plans</u></h2>
<div id="space"><br></div>
<h3><u>1)Expenses</u></h3>
<div id="space"><br></div>
<div id="form">
<form action="">
<div id="Location"><input type="checkbox" name="placename" onclick="ShowEditLoc(this)" />Location
<div id="editloc" style="display:none">
<table>
<tr><td>City:</td>
<td><input type="text" value="Please enter City name.." size="50"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>State:</td>
<td><input type="text" value="Please enter State name.." size="50" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Country:</td>
<td><input type="text" value="Please enter Country name.." size="50" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="save" /></td><td><input type="button" value="reset" /></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWT28/2/)

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css"></style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2><u>Plans</u></h2>

        <div id="space">
            <br/>
        </div>
         <h3><u>1)Expenses</u></h3>

        <div id="space">
            <br/>
        </div>
        <input id="Location" type="checkbox" name="placename" />Location
        <div id="form">
            <form action="">
                <div id="editloc">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>City:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" value="Please enter City name.." size="50" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>State:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" value="Please enter State name.." size="50" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Country:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" value="Please enter Country name.." size="50" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" value="save" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" value="reset" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
#form {
    display:none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on("change", "#Location", function () {
    var obj = $(this);
    if (obj.is(":checked")) $("#form").show();
    else $("#form").hide();
});
```